# Poor alignment of popover arrow in Inbox filter popup

Tags: bug, design, global-inbox, tooltips

The inbox filter popup has poor alignment for the popover arrow/ ^-mark relative to the popup rectangle.

> [image]

In Unread mode even the border line looks broken:

> [image]

Zoomed in:

> [image: Zoomed in]

Compare with unread popup on ruSO:

> [image]

Comment: What makes the position "invalid"? Looks fine to me. If you would like to have it in different place then you can start a new feature request.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars see update.

Comment: OK, what about it? How is it related? Those are two different places, each and its own design based on the available space and other factors SE graphic designers thought about.

Comment: The alignment is very clearly "invalid" because it hangs over the rounded corner of the box, obscuring it from view and breaking the borders continuity. That's a bug, not a design choice. Tweaked the wording slightly though, just to be extra super duper clear.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I updated the case to compare with more relevant.

Comment: I honestly see no issue here. Nothing at all. The arrow is 100% fine. I am glad for you that others do, somehow.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmVEo.png) is what it looks like for me. It's a bit oddly aligned, but it's so small I never looked at it closely enough to notice anything.